# Append an element to the beginning of every sublist in a a list

Tags: haskell

```
concatr ::Integer -> [[Integer]] -> [[Integer]]
concatr x (y)    = [x] : y
concatr x (y:ys) = concatr x y:  concatr x ys
```

I have tried so many combinations of this that my head is starting to hurt. What exactly am i doing wrong? I just want an integer to be put in every sublist of a list passed in.

Comment: Notice that for the posted "solution" the first pattern always matches  (`concatr x (y) == concatr x y`), so this is always equal to `[ [x] , rest or original list ]`.  You must deconstruct the original list, as you tried to do in the second case (but failed to use `(x:y)` instead of `concatr x y`) and terminate with a null case `concatr x []`.

Comment: Sorry, I said "the posted solution" when referring to the proposed code in the question.  That is probably confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `map` function.

```
concatr :: Integer -> [[Integer]] -> [[Integer]]
concatr x ys = map (x:) ys
```

Eta reduce for a terse solution:

```
concatr x = map (x:)
```

Comment: I made the answer a little bit more liberal.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't mean for it to sound like there was a unique solution!

Comment: You can go right down to `concatr = map . (:)` for a fully point-free (point-less?) styled function!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `map`:

```
concatr :: Integer -> [[Integer]] -> [[Integer]]
concatr x []     = []
concatr x (y:ys) = (x:y):concatr x ys
```

Two cases:

- If the list is empty, we return an empty list.
- If the list is `y:ys`, the new head is `x:y`, and we call recursively `concatr` on remaining part.

Example: `concatr 1 [[0],[2]]` is `[[1,0],[1,2]`.